# SQL equality showing incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am having simple issue with my SQL studio. I am selecting 2 fields:

```
  SELECT Project, OperationName
  FROM [LESTO].[UserData].[Orders]
  where project='SLS002701'
```

And the following result is:

[image]

Obviously there is OperationName that is called ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING. But when I try:

```
SELECT Project, OperationName
FROM [LESTO].[UserData].[Orders]
where OperationName = 'ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING'
```

There is no result (0). How is this possible?

Comment: What is your `OperationName` column data type?

Comment: You can try `SELECT Project, OperationName FROM [LESTO].[UserData].[Orders]
where OperationName  LIKE  'ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING%' ` . If it select the rows that you expected then check data in `OperationName ` column

Comment: @zhorov nvarchar(99)

Comment: I tried also with LIKE and same result @KiranDesai

Comment: @BorislavStefanov `where OperationName = N'ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING'` will work.

Comment: @Zhorov Thanks a lot! It worked

Comment: @BorislavStefanov you're searching a Unicode field using an *ASCII* string. The string you typed will be treated as ASCII using whatever codepage corresponds to the server's collation. Use `N'ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING'` to create a Unicode literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT Project, OperationName
FROM [LESTO].[UserData].[Orders]
where OperationName = N'ОПАКОВАНЕ/PACKING'
```

For nvarchar you require N' when non-Unicode characters.